# Autocomplete directory/folder path in Atom (for python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, ide, intellisense, atom-editor

I am a novice python user and I use Atom to code in python. Sometimes, I use python 'os' module to get the working directory and in some cases, I have to navigate through directory/folders to get to where I want the code to run. e.g. say my starting working directory is "C:\Users\XYZ" and I want to change directory to some folder named "ABC" in some directory path under D:. Currently, I have to open an explorer window to figure out where the 'ABC' folder is and then copy paste the directory in Atom and swap '\' with '\' and use os.chdir function. Is there an easier way or some Atom package where I press the first letter of the folder and it gives me autocomplete suggestions? I tried os.listdir() but copy paste using that is too cumbersome. I know that I can just create my file in that directory to start with but I want to learn if I can navigate through folders the way using autocomplete suggestions.
Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not exactly what you want but may help you. There is an Atom extension "platformio-ide-terminal" which when run will open a regular bash shell at the bottom of your Atom window. Using this you can easily move around your directories using unix commands. Hope this helps some.